# conditional compilation of code and resources in android

Tags: resources, compilation, conditional-statements

I have a problem regarding conditional compilation.

I want to conditionally selected resources and build seperate apk for that in android.

How do I achieve this in android.

I am using Eclipse.

Thanks,

Comment: take a look at this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/GlIWpRejTFQ